# Sequence of function calling in php that is in one line

Tags: php

I am new in php and i want to know what is the sequence of function calling in php like for example what will execute first in this line.

```
echo reset(unpack("i", pack("i", hexdec("FFFFFFFE"))));
```

Comment: inner functions will execute first. it's output will be processed by the next function.
hexdec > pack > unpack > reset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Order of operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389422/php-order-of-operations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following sample :

```php
$result = function1("value", function2(TRUE, ($test ? $test : -1)));
```

The `$result` variable contains the result of the execution of `function1()` with two parameters :

- `"value"` which will be sent as-is
- the return value of `function2()` with two parameters :

  - `TRUE`
  - the result of the ternary `($test ? $test : -1)`

So the order of processigng will be :

1. `$test ? $test : -1`
2. `function2()`
3. `function1()`

Hope this is clear enough !